# ¿Cómo guardar una cadena de caracteres ingresada por el usuario sin conocer de antemano el tamaño de la cadena?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

Este es el [problema](https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/Backspacing).

Hice el código que lo que hace es tomar una cadena de caracteres ingresada por el usuario, y pasarlo a una pila para luego poder quitar caracteres segun el número de veces que se indique.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    struct Nodo
    {
        char dato;
        Nodo *siguiente;
    };
    
    void agregarPila(Nodo *&,char);
    void sacarPila(Nodo *&,char &);
    
    int main()
    {
        Nodo *pila = NULL;
        char cad[100];
        int longitud = 0;
        int i = 0, n = 0;
        
        cin.getline(cad, 100,'\n');
        longitud = strlen(cad);
        
        for(i = 0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            agregarPila(pila, cad[i]);
        }
        cin>>n;
        //sacar n caracteres del arreglo
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            sacarPila(pila,cad[longitud-1]);
            longitud--;
        }
        
        //imprimir cadena de caracteres
        for(i = 0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            cout<<cad[i];
        }             
                                                                                                    
        return 0;
    }
    
    void agregarPila(Nodo *&pila,char n)
    {
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = pila;
    pila = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    
    void sacarPila(Nodo *&pila,char &n)
    {
    Nodo *aux = pila;
    n = aux->dato;
    pila = aux->siguiente;
    delete aux;
    }
```

Pero tiene un problema, y es que el arreglo `char cad[100];` ya tiene un tamaño definido, y si la cadena ingresada por el usuario sobrepasa el límite me salta un error y no funciona como espero.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se capaz de soportar una cadena de hasta 10⁹ caracteres?
para poder pasarlos a una pila y luego eliminar los N caracteres indicados por el usuario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Usando `string`, tal vez?

```
std::string cad;
...
getline(cin, cad);
cin.clear();
```

La longitud máxima del string se valida con `max_size()` y está en el orden de los millones de carácteres.

Comment: esta genial, pero ¿como puedo pasar un string a una pila caracter por caracter?  ya que el problema me pide eliminar N caracteres como si fuera la tecla de borrar del teclado

Comment: @Hermit esa es OTRA pregunta y hace parte de cómo resuelves el reto. Revisa la documentación de strings en c++, hay métodos pa eso :)

Comment: Ok, gracias, voy a hecharle un ojo a la documentacion

Comment: @Hermit puedes usar la función [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) o el operador [`[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) para acceder a cada caracter. Tocaría copiar de a uno a la pila. Por cierto, debes incluir la librería con `#include <string>` (no es lo mismo que `#include <string.h>`)

Comment: @Mateo vale lo voy a probar